# summing 2 numbers with n^2 digits using Full Adders and 2x1 Mux with t_pd=O(n)

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

I have a task to design a circuit that sums 2 numbers with n^2  digits each in base 2.
The only restriction I have is that the total t_pd  is  O(n)
So in my line of thought I assumed that  n+n+n+...n==n^2
Hence if I sum them parallelly with n FA's in each row that calculate the first nth' digits, second nth' digits and so on.

I can get that  t_pd  but my issue is that I haven't used any Mux, and that I don't know how
to account for the carry out of each row into the next without crippling my t_pd
This is the kind of circuit I had in mind:

x and y are the two numbers im summing and z is the result.
[image]

Would appreciate any insight as of how to add the carry outs and muxes.
I'm allowed to use boolean constants

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [`carry look ahead adder`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder) ? Each sub block of `n` bits is carry look ahead adder. The `n` such blocks are then connected in ripple carry adder. Would that give `O(n)` ?

Comment: If the numbers are length n^2 and you need O(n), the algorithm has to be O(sqrt(W)), where W is the number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, in the end I think I found a solution that looks like:
[image]